# How to move MySQL Credentials to a include.h?

Tags: c

The following code works OK.however..
 
I want to move the MySQL credentials to **test.h**

**script.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "test.h"

int main() {

while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) { 

char query[300];

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

char *server = "localhost";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "";  
char *database = "a";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if (mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {

sprintf(query, "select * from table  limit 1");
mysql_query(conn, query);

res = mysql_use_result(conn);
row = mysql_fetch_row(res);


}

printf("Content-type: text/html;\r\n");
printf("\r\n");
printf("%s", row[1]);

FCGI_Finish();
}

  return 0;
}
```

OK let's copy and move all of these to test.h
**test.h**

```
char query[300];

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;

char *server = "localhost";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "";  
char *database = "a";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

attempt to compile **script.c**

```
In file included from test.c:7:
test.h:11: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
test.h:11: error: conflicting types for 'conn'
test.h:3: note: previous declaration of 'conn' was here
test.h:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test.h:11: error: initializer element is not constant
```

there is actually more errors. I only pasted the first few lines.

Comment: To be honest.. I would like to also move the mysql_real_connect to the test.h file that way I am free to simply ask "is mysql connected ? if yes.. then run this query " in my scripts.

Comment: is my only option to place it all into a function inside test.h ? and then send my query to that function as an argument.. and have it respond (return) with the outcome ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#define` in the header file.

```
// test.h
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define PASSWORD ""
```

Keep the rest in the source code file.

```
// script.c
char *server = SERVER;
char *user = USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use functions from `script.c` in other C source files, your best option is to:

- Define these functions in `script.c`.
- **Declare** these functions in `test.h` (BTW - common naming convention will be `script.h`).
- Then you can **include** `test.h` from any other `.c` file (that compiles together with `script.c`) and use these functions that are declared there.

Regarding the variables - you can either `#define` them in the `.h` file, or leave them in the `.c` file and **wrap** them using getter functions, and then declare these functions in the same I wrote above for functions. For example:

In the `script.c` you'll have:

```
char *server = "localhost";
...
const char *get_server(void)
{
    return server;
}
```

And in the `.h` file you'll declare:

```
const char *get_server(void);
```

Sometimes it is necessary to put function *definitions* in `.h` files, but usually you have to have a good reason for that (like *inline functions* for example). In your case you don't need it, keep it in the `.c` source file.