# Move " MYSQL *conn; " to " external.h "?

Tags: c

I was able to move certain things of MySQL to an external.h

external.h

```
#define server "localhost"
#define user "root"
#define pass ""
#define db "a"
```

I also want to move these to there:

```
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

this is my current WORKING script.c

script.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "external.h"

int main() {

bool x;

MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);

x = mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, pass, db, 0, NULL, 0);
if (x==1){
    printf("connected");
}
```

}

How can I for example move..

```
    MYSQL *conn;
```

to external.h ?

Comment: Do not define variables in header files. This is dangerous and useless.

Comment: Hmm I remember I [answered this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44464772/6032010) today...

Comment: `#define pass ""` - are you serious?? Hardcoded passwords are a definitive no-go!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your global variables in header file as:

external.h

```
MYEXTERN MYSQL *conn;
MYEXTERN MYSQL_RES *res;
MYEXTERN MYSQL_ROW row;
```

in script.c you will include external.h as

```
#define MYEXTERN
#include "external.h"
```

in all other c file say other.c you will include it as

```
#define MYEXTERN extern
#include "external.h"
```

so that in other.c your global variables get declared as extern, this way you will have your global variables declared in header file, yet you will not get error for variables being redefined when you include them in more that one object

You can not put MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL); in header file as compiler expects constants to be assigned to during global variables initialization, it should be kept in main function or any other initializer function you might want to define.